# Tensorflow reducing learning rates of saved model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am working on cnn model which has 4 conv layers and 3 dense layers. dataset have around 28000 images and 7000 test images. The model has saved checkpoints and I have trained it several times and achieved 60 % accuracy so far, and while training learning rate is reduced to 2.6214403e-07 (as i used ReduceLROnPlateau factor 0.4). I have question if I increased the learning rate say 1e-4. and resumed the training how will it effect my model? Is It a good idea?

[accuracy vs epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTjvX.png)

Comment: when did the learning rate switch to 2.6e-7? That depends much on the learning curve, can you show it here? If you resume it with a bigger lr, it may reset everything you have learnt, but can reach the minimization quicker if you assume that the current lr is too small and not sufficient

Comment: i have edited the graph now

Comment: @dtlam26 I disagree because you don't see overfitting yet which signals that the network is capable to a) reach higher accuracies and b) reach them faster with a higher learning rate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your learning curve plateaus immediately and doesn't change much beyond the initial few epochs (as in your case), then your learning rate is too low. While you can resume training with higher learning rates, it would likely render any progress of the initial epochs meaningless. Since you typically only *decrease* the learning rate between epochs, and given the slow initial progress of your network, you should simply retrain with an *increased* initial learning rate until you see larger changes in the first few epochs. You can then identify the point of convergence by whenever overfitting happens (test accuracy goes down while train accuracy goes up) and stop there. If this point is still "unnecessarily late", you can additionally reduce the amount that the learning rate decays to make faster progress between epochs.